# Write textfile from spark streaming

Tags: scala, apache-spark, spark-streaming

The following is a sample code for translating with Spark Streaming

```
object StreamingTranslator {

  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    if (args.length != 4) {
      System.err.println(
        "Usage: StreamingTranslateApp <appname> <book_path> <output_path> <language>")
      System.exit(1)
    }

    val Seq(appName, bookPath, outputPath, lang) = args.toSeq

    val dict = getDictionary(lang)

    val conf = new SparkConf()
         .setAppName(appName)
         .setJars(SparkContext.jarOfClass(this.getClass).toSeq)

    val ssc = new StreamingContext(conf, Seconds(1))

    val book = ssc.textFileStream(bookPath)

    val translated = book.map(line => line.split("\\s+").map(word => dict.getOrElse(word, word)).mkString(" ")).persist()

    translated.saveAsTextFiles(outputPath)

    ssc.start()

    ssc.awaitTermination()
  }

  def getDictionary(lang: String): Map[String, String] = {
    if (!Set("German", "French", "Italian", "Spanish").contains(lang)) {
      System.err.println(
        "Unsupported language: %s".format(lang))
      System.exit(1)
    }
    val url = "http://www.june29.com/IDP/files/%s.txt".format(lang)
    println("Grabbing dictionary from: %s".format(url))
    Source.fromURL(url, "ISO-8859-1").mkString
      .split("\\r?\\n")
      .filter(line => !line.startsWith("#"))
      .map(line => line.split("\\t"))
      .map(tkns => (tkns(0).trim, tkns(1).trim)).toMap
  }

}
```

The code however fails with a NullPointerException below

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
        at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:1012)
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell.runCommand(Shell.java:483)
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell.run(Shell.java:456)
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell$ShellCommandExecutor.execute(Shell.java:722)
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell.execCommand(Shell.java:815)
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell.execCommand(Shell.java:798)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileUtil.execCommand(FileUtil.java:1097)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.RawLocalFileSystem$DeprecatedRawLocalFileStatus.loadPermissionInfo(RawLocalFileSystem.java:657)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.RawLocalFileSystem$DeprecatedRawLocalFileStatus.getPermission(RawLocalFileSystem.java:632)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.LocatedFileStatus.<init>(LocatedFileStatus.java:49)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem$4.next(FileSystem.java:1729)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem$4.next(FileSystem.java:1711)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input.FileInputFormat.singleThreadedListStatus(FileInputFormat.java:305)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input.FileInputFormat.listStatus(FileInputFormat.java:265)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input.FileInputFormat.getSplits(FileInputFormat.java:387)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.NewHadoopRDD.getPartitions(NewHadoopRDD.scala:121)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$partitions$2.apply(RDD.scala:248)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$partitions$2.apply(RDD.scala:246)
        at scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:121)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.partitions(RDD.scala:246)
        at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.FileInputDStream$$anonfun$5.apply(FileInputDStream.scala:285)
        at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.FileInputDStream$$anonfun$5.apply(FileInputDStream.scala:275)
        at scala.collection.TraversableLike$$anonfun$map$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:234)
        at scala.collection.TraversableLike$$anonfun$map$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:234)
        at scala.collection.IndexedSeqOptimized$class.foreach(IndexedSeqOptimized.scala:33)
        at scala.collection.mutable.WrappedArray.foreach(WrappedArray.scala:35)
        at scala.collection.TraversableLike$class.map(TraversableLike.scala:234)
        at scala.collection.AbstractTraversable.map(Traversable.scala:104)
        at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.FileInputDStream.org$apache$spark$streaming$dstream$FileInputDStream$$filesToRDD(FileInputDStream.scala:275)
        at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.FileInputDStream.compute(FileInputDStream.scala:155)
        at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.DStream$$anonfun$getOrCompute$1$$anonfun$1$$anonfun$apply$7.apply(DStream.scala:341)
        at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.DStream$$anonfun$getOrCompute$1$$anonfun$1$$anonfun$apply$7.apply(DStream.scala:341)
        at scala.util.DynamicVariable.withValue(DynamicVariable.scala:58)
        at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.DStream$$anonfun$getOrCompute$1$$anonfun$1.apply(DStream.scala:340)
        at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.DStream$$anonfun$getOrCompute$1$$anonfun$1.apply(DStream.scala:340)
        at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.DStream.createRDDWithLocalProperties(DStream.scala:415)
        at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.DStream$$anonfun$getOrCompute$1.apply(DStream.scala:335)
        at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.DStream$$anonfun$getOrCompute$1.apply(DStream.scala:333)
        at scala.Option.orElse(Option.scala:289)
        at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.DStream.getOrCompute(DStream.scala:330)
        at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.MappedDStream.compute(MappedDStream.scala:36)
        at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.DStream$$anonfun$getOrCompute$1$$anonfun$1$$anonfun$apply$7.apply(DStream.scala:341)
        at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.DStream$$anonfun$getOrCompute$1$$anonfun$1$$anonfun$apply$7.apply(DStream.scala:341)
        at scala.util.DynamicVariable.withValue(DynamicVariable.scala:58)
        at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.DStream$$anonfun$getOrCompute$1$$anonfun$1.apply(DStream.scala:340)
        at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.DStream$$anonfun$getOrCompute$1$$anonfun$1.apply(DStream.scala:340)
        at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.DStream.createRDDWithLocalProperties(DStream.scala:415)
        at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.DStream$$anonfun$getOrCompute$1.apply(DStream.scala:335)
        at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.DStream$$anonfun$getOrCompute$1.apply(DStream.scala:333)
        at scala.Option.orElse(Option.scala:289)
        at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.DStream.getOrCompute(DStream.scala:330)
        at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.MappedDStream.compute(MappedDStream.scala:36)
        at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.DStream$$anonfun$getOrCompute$1$$anonfun$1$$anonfun$apply$7.apply(DStream.scala:341)
        at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.DStream$$anonfun$getOrCompute$1$$anonfun$1$$anonfun$apply$7.apply(DStream.scala:341)
        at scala.util.DynamicVariable.withValue(DynamicVariable.scala:58)
        at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.DStream$$anonfun$getOrCompute$1$$anonfun$1.apply(DStream.scala:340)
        at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.DStream$$anonfun$getOrCompute$1$$anonfun$1.apply(DStream.scala:340)
        at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.DStream.createRDDWithLocalProperties(DStream.scala:415)
        at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.DStream$$anonfun$getOrCompute$1.apply(DStream.scala:335)
        at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.DStream$$anonfun$getOrCompute$1.apply(DStream.scala:333)
        at scala.Option.orElse(Option.scala:289)
        at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.DStream.getOrCompute(DStream.scala:330)
        at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.TransformedDStream$$anonfun$6.apply(TransformedDStream.scala:42)
        at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.TransformedDStream$$anonfun$6.apply(TransformedDStream.scala:42)
        at scala.collection.TraversableLike$$anonfun$map$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:234)
        at scala.collection.TraversableLike$$anonfun$map$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:234)
        at scala.collection.immutable.List.foreach(List.scala:381)
        at scala.collection.TraversableLike$class.map(TraversableLike.scala:234)
        at scala.collection.immutable.List.map(List.scala:285)
        at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.TransformedDStream.compute(TransformedDStream.scala:42)
        at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.DStream$$anonfun$getOrCompute$1$$anonfun$1$$anonfun$apply$7.apply(DStream.scala:341)
        at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.DStream$$anonfun$getOrCompute$1$$anonfun$1$$anonfun$apply$7.apply(DStream.scala:341)
        at scala.util.DynamicVariable.withValue(DynamicVariable.scala:58)
        at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.DStream$$anonfun$getOrCompute$1$$anonfun$1.apply(DStream.scala:340)
        at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.DStream$$anonfun$getOrCompute$1$$anonfun$1.apply(DStream.scala:340)
        at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.DStream.createRDDWithLocalProperties(DStream.scala:415)
        at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.TransformedDStream.createRDDWithLocalProperties(TransformedDStream.scala:65)
        at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.DStream$$anonfun$getOrCompute$1.apply(DStream.scala:335)
        at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.DStream$$anonfun$getOrCompute$1.apply(DStream.scala:333)
        at scala.Option.orElse(Option.scala:289)
        at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.DStream.getOrCompute(DStream.scala:330)
        at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.ForEachDStream.generateJob(ForEachDStream.scala:48)
        at org.apache.spark.streaming.DStreamGraph$$anonfun$1.apply(DStreamGraph.scala:117)
        at org.apache.spark.streaming.DStreamGraph$$anonfun$1.apply(DStreamGraph.scala:116)
        at scala.collection.TraversableLike$$anonfun$flatMap$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:241)
        at scala.collection.TraversableLike$$anonfun$flatMap$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:241)
        at scala.collection.mutable.ResizableArray$class.foreach(ResizableArray.scala:59)
        at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.foreach(ArrayBuffer.scala:48)
        at scala.collection.TraversableLike$class.flatMap(TraversableLike.scala:241)
        at scala.collection.AbstractTraversable.flatMap(Traversable.scala:104)
        at org.apache.spark.streaming.DStreamGraph.generateJobs(DStreamGraph.scala:116)
        at org.apache.spark.streaming.scheduler.JobGenerator$$anonfun$3.apply(JobGenerator.scala:248)
        at org.apache.spark.streaming.scheduler.JobGenerator$$anonfun$3.apply(JobGenerator.scala:246)
        at scala.util.Try$.apply(Try.scala:192)
        at org.apache.spark.streaming.scheduler.JobGenerator.generateJobs(JobGenerator.scala:246)
        at org.apache.spark.streaming.scheduler.JobGenerator.org$apache$spark$streaming$scheduler$JobGenerator$$processEvent(JobGenerator.scala:182)
        at org.apache.spark.streaming.scheduler.JobGenerator$$anon$1.onReceive(JobGenerator.scala:88)
        at org.apache.spark.streaming.scheduler.JobGenerator$$anon$1.onReceive(JobGenerator.scala:87)
        at org.apache.spark.util.EventLoop$$anon$1.run(EventLoop.scala:48)
```

any help appreaciated!!

Comment: The exception is due to writing to text file, but there is no clear indication of what is the error, though an empty _SUCCESS file is written

Comment: Was able to resolve it, running it the first time, so was not aware of that winutils.exe must be present